# Adding Onclick() to items in a ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, onclicklistener

I've created a horizontal scroll consisting of multiple items (images and text), but how can I add an on-click event to each of these items.

I have followed this tutorial to get where I am now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTJm1Ys9jMI

MainActivity.java:

```
 CarouselPicker carouselPicker1, carouselPicker2, carouselPicker3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        carouselPicker1 = (CarouselPicker) findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker1);
        carouselPicker2 = (CarouselPicker) findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker2);
        carouselPicker3 = (CarouselPicker) findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker3);


//Carousel 1 with all images

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImages = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, itemsImages, 0);
        carouselPicker1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        //Carousel 2 with all text

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> textItems = new ArrayList<>();
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("One", 20));
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Two", 20));
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Three", 20));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter textAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, textItems, 0);
        carouselPicker2.setAdapter(textAdapter);

        //Carousel 3 with both

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> mixItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("One", 20));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Three", 20));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter mixAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, mixItems, 0);
        carouselPicker3.setAdapter(mixAdapter);
```

Activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker
        android:id="@+id/carouselPicker1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:items_visible="three"

        />

    <in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker
        android:id="@+id/carouselPicker2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:items_visible="three"
        />

    <in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker
        android:id="@+id/carouselPicker3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:items_visible="three"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle Scripts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //add Library
    implementation "com.github.Vatican-Cameos:CarouselPicker:v1.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
```

How can I add a button functionality to each image shown in MainActivy.java?

**Here is the New Code in MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.carouselpicker;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselPicker carouselPicker1, carouselPicker2, carouselPicker3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        carouselPicker1 = findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker1);
        carouselPicker2 = findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker2);
        carouselPicker3 = findViewById(R.id.carouselPicker3);


//Carousel 1 with all images

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImages = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, itemsImages, 0);
        carouselPicker1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        //Carousel 2 with all text

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> textItems = new ArrayList<>();
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("One", 20));
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Two", 20));
        textItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Three", 20));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter textAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, textItems, 0);
        carouselPicker2.setAdapter(textAdapter);

        //Carousel 3 with both

        List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> mixItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("One", 20));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.TextItem("Three", 20));
        mixItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter mixAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, mixItems, 0);
        carouselPicker3.setAdapter(mixAdapter);

        carouselPicker1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //position of the selected item
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        toast.show();

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Toast oast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        oast.show();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // do smth else
                        break;
                    //case 3, etc...

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do as explained here:

https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker

Set listener for each of the Carousel pickers, and then use switch-case for specific logic for each position:

```
carouselPicker.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //position of the selected item
                switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            //do smth
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "first item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                        case 1:
                            // do smth else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "second item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                        //case 3, etc... 


                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: what exactly does this do:   switch (position) {
                        case 1:
                            //do smth
                        break;

                        case 2:
                            // do smth else
                        break;
                        //case 3, etc...

Comment: How do I add it for each carousel? and are the cases the position?

Comment: No, the position is the position if the item that was selected in the first carousel. For others do "carouselPicker2.addOnPageChangeListener(...

Comment: then what does "Case" do

Comment: Im still not sure how to implement this. Maybe this will help:    When I click one of the items, I want it to run a function. For now lets just have it create a toast message. As of know I have 3 carousels, each with different items, and I want a different function for each item to run when it is clicked. I'm just not sure how to implement this 3 times (once for each) and how to get the button/function to work

Comment: Within the case 0: You do the code that You want to do if the user selected first item. case 1: second item

Comment: ok, next question, when I add this to MainActivity (at the bottom) the compiler says: error: non-static method addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, but the function runs when the item is shown, I want to click on the item, then run the function. -- For example, when I swipe though the images, when the specific image is in the center, it runs the function. I don't want this as it will run all the functions if I swipe to the end. I want to be able to look at the images, then click the image and have it run its function.

Comment: Make sure You put the switch in onPageSelected and not in onPageScrolled

Comment: Yep, I copied your code, so it should be good. I added (edited) what the code looks now like in the original post in a new section, take a look.

Comment: any ideas to get it working? (call the function when clicked, not when it is selected [its in the middle])

Comment: Perhaps keep the selected number within a global variable, and put the onclicklistener on the carousel picker itself?

Comment: ya that's kinda what i did, it works alright, thanks for all the help. 1 answer tick for you! :) thanks